# Hanging artwork on plastered brick?

Tags: walls, plaster, hanging

I’m wanting to hang a couple things on my wall (small mirror, picture, light wall hanging etc) but the walls are brick, covered in plaster and paint so i cannot use 3M hooks - pulls the paint off, and hammering a nail straight in chipped the plaster off. 
How do I go about putting up a small picture hook without chipping off the plaster and damaging the wall - so only a little hole is left ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small masonry drill bit in an electric drill, slow speed:

[image]

small plastic or lead anchor:

[image]

small picture hook with hole for appropriate anchor screw:
[image]

or larger versions of all this for larger pieces

Answer (score 0):

If the picture is valuable, I’d be concerned about hanging it on a brick wall that could 1) sweat, 2) have condensation, 3) stain the picture via brick or mortar, etc. You may want to isolate the picture from the wall. I’d consult a curator...just to be sure.